# Colocar imágenes con diseño adaptable usando bootstrap y HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo 15 imágenes que colocar en el cuerpo del HTML. Sólo puedo usar HTML y bootstrap, nada más.

Necesito hacer uso del diseño adaptable para que quede así: en pantallas grandes 5 imágenes por fila, en pantallas de tabletas 3 imágenes por fila y en móviles 1 imagen por fila.

Puedo conseguir cualquiera de las 3 opciones pero no a la vez, esto es, si consigo sacar en pantalla grande las 5 imágenes por fila al reducir la pantalla se descoloca todo y viceversa. El diseño para móviles funciona bien con cualquiera, ¿alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Por favor, comparte el HTML que has probado para indicarte cómo hacerlo de manera correcta.

Comment: Te recomendaría repasar más sobre [rejillas de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).